# getting CORS error when I try to fetch my api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to fetch my API from my react app, it shows me this error message when my laptop is connected through a LAN connection.
[image]

But when my laptop is connected through a mobile hotspot, it doesn't show me any error.
And when I run my API in localhost:5000, it shows me this error message on the terminal.

```
Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

I already give access to my IP address and it's working fine when I connected through a mobile hotspot.

Why is it happening and how to fix this?

I am able to fetch other APIs but not mine.
API link: https://invoicesapi.herokuapp.com/api/invoices
Github Repo: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/invoice_api

API app.js code:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

// routes
const invoices = require('./routes/api/invoices');

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Content-Type, Authorization");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    next();
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Connect Database
connectDB();

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
});

app.use('/api', invoices);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is started');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the cors package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
npm install cors
```

Add this to app.js file:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://yoursite.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Comment: It worked!
Should I remove this code?
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Content-Type, Authorization");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    next();
});

Comment: yes, you dont need it anymore, because cors package is doing it all for you :)

Comment: then will remove that
thanks